# Export variable from within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I export `isDark` from the Theme component? Or is it possible to query `isDark` from another file without exporting it?

`Toggle.js`:

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";
import { Particles as ReactParticles } from 'react-particles-js';
import usePersistentState from '../hooks/PersistentState';

const Theme = () => {
    const [isDark, setIsDark] = usePersistentState('theme', true); // default to dark mode

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isDark) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('other');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('other');
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <main>
                <input id="toggle" name="toggle" type="checkbox" checked={isDark} onChange={event => setIsDark(event.target.checked)} />
                <label htmlFor="toggle" className="switch" id="switch"></label>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

class Toggle extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Theme />
        );
    }
}

export default Toggle;
```

Where I am trying to use `isDark`, `Background.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { isDark } from './Toggle' <- doesnt work obviously
console.log(isDark)

const PARAMS = {
    "text": {
        "color": {
            "value": `${isDark ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF'}`
        },
        ...
```

Where `PARAMS` is used:

```js
class Background extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="particles">
                <ReactParticles width='100vw' height="100vh" params={PARAMS} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not React-ish, but you could assign to an outside variable as well as calling `setIsDark`, and export that variable

Comment: Where are you looking to use `isDark` elsewhere? In a component that's a parent of the `Toggle` component?

Comment: So it's used in `PARAMS`, where is `PARAMS` used? There might be a React way of doing this if it's in another component, but if not there's always the other option

Comment: I have edited the post to add more context. `Background.js` is not a parent or child of `Toggle.js`. They both sit at the same level in the same folder within the project.

Comment: If they're React siblings (or are even anywhere inside the same tree), it should be doable via React

Answer (score 0):

Use a hook. Call it something like `useTheme` and have it return the read theme values. You might also consider using contexts so you can cache the theme value in the context provider.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-villani-vysg6?file=/src/App.js) is an example. You can see that i create a context value that can hold onto a single theme instance that can later be injected via useTheme. You can add whatever you want to the context object, and allow the hook to selectively export those values to the consumer. This is nice because the hook can take a bunch of verbose values and setters and provide a api that's more ergonomic for consumers. This is how react-redux and react-router work.

Comment: How would I use a hook in this scenario to read the values?

Comment: I updated my answer for you containing an example. You will need to figure out how to make it suite your needs.